# Update Firebase User's email and password after loginWithCustomToken on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

My use case is similar to [Parse Suggested Migration Strategy](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/parse-android#suggested-migration-strategy_1)

(but I'm not using Parse, just integrating 3rd party auth)

On Node.js / express, here is relevant code:

```js
firebaseWebSDK.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken)
    .then(user => {

        let nextStep
        let message
        // check if returned user has "email" field set..
        if (!user.email) {
            message = 'Signed up user, saved: email, password, and display name.'
            const usersRef = firebaseServerSDK.database().ref('users')
            nextStep = Promise.all([
                user.updateEmail(email),
                user.updatePassword(password),
                user.updateProfile({ displayName }),
                usersRef.child(user.uid).set({ displayName, email }),
            ])
        } else {
            message = `User already exists for that email: ${email}`
            nextStep = Promise.resolve(null)
        }
        nextStep.then(() => {
            delete req.session.user
            return res.json({ message })
        })
        .catch(updateError => res.json({ error: updateError.message }))
    })
    .catch(signInError => {
        const errorCode = signInError.code
        const errorMessage = signInError.message

        return res.json({ type: 'signInError', errorCode, errorMessage })
    })
```

Here's what happens:

- Sometimes user email updates, sometimes it doesn't
- Never does the password update
- Pretty sure the Profile updates always
- database "/users" saves correctly, no issues there.

Always tested with new user, so it's always entering the "update" branch of code...

Any ideas? Code follows structure of documentation linked above, so not sure what issue is.